# Deleting object from its member function

Tags: c++, delete-operator

We have a `container` object and an `item` object. `Item` is part of the `container`. The `item` member function calls `container` function which deletes the `item`.

What happens when `container` function that deleted `item` object returns to the `item` member function? It sounds like it leads to undefined behaviour. Is this a more elaborate case of `delete this;`?

edit:

```
class Item
{
   Container* itemContainer;
   std::string itemName;

   void check(void)
   {
       bool condition = false;

       // check some condition (not relevant to the question)

       if (!condition)
       {
           itemContainer->CheckFailed(itemName);
       } 
   }
}

class Container
{
    std::vector<Item*> itemList;
    void checkFailed(std::string)
    {
        Item* targetItem;

        //find item by name

        delete targetItem;
    }
}
```

So my question was: what happens if `condition` is false and `checkFailed` from `Container` is called (`targetItem` is the `item` from where the `Check()` function is called).

Comment: Can you example your situation with some code?  It would make this a lot more clear.

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is well defined (or not undefined).

More specifically, the behaviour is well-defined if the object was created with operator `new`, and is not used after being `delete`d (e.g. a [now dangling] pointer to it is dereferenced, a non-static member is accessed, a non-static member function called, etc).

If the object is used after being deleted, then the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a more elaborate case of delete this, once the `Container::checkFailed()` returns to `Item::check()` the this* (and any/all members of the Item instance) are gone and cannot be used without undefined behavior.