# Erase member from list during member erase function

Tags: c++, list, pointers, memory-management

I have container object with some members (eg. vector), and I need to erase the member from list. But I need to do it througth the member erase function.
Bellow is example.
This system cause, that the program return to function of the non-existed object, in one moment.
Is this the proper way? Cannot it cause unexpected behavior of program?

```
  using namespace std;

  class CCont;
  class CMember
  {
  public:
    int m_iIndex;
    CString m_csName;
    CCont *m_pParent;

    CMember(CCont *pParent, CString csName, int iIndex);
    bool Erase(); //return trtue, if erasing is successfull

  };

  class CCont : protected vector <CMember *>
  {
  public:
    //Add member to list
    void AddMember(CString csName, int iIndex)
    {
        CMember *pMem = new CMember(this, csName, iIndex);
        push_back(pMem);
    }

    //find member in list by index / name a return pointer
    CMember *FindMember(int iIndex) const
    {
        for(auto memb : *this)
            if(memb->m_iIndex == iIndex)
                return memb;
        return NULL;
    }

    CMember *FindMember(LPCTSTR lsName) const
    {
        for(auto memb : *this)
            if(memb->m_csName == lsName)
                return memb;
        return NULL;
    }

    bool EraseMemb(CMember *pMemb)
    {
        iterator it;
        for(it = begin(); it != end(); ++it)
            if(*it == pMemb)
                break;
        if(it == end())
            return false;
        delete *it;
        erase(it);
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CCont cCont;
    cCont.AddMember(L"Smith", 1);
    cCont.AddMember(L"Novak", 3);
    cCont.AddMember(L"Johny", 4);
    CMember *pSmith = cCont.FindMember(L"Smith");
    if(pSmith)
        pSmith->Erase();
    //pSimth is now pointer to non-existend object, but I will not use pSmith nevermore

    int debug = 0;
    return 0;
}

//--------implementation----------

CMember::CMember(CCont *pParent, CString csName, int iIndex)
    : m_pParent(pParent), m_csName(csName), m_iIndex(iIndex)
{}

bool CMember::Erase()
{
    return m_pParent->EraseMemb(this);
    //here I am returning to function of the non-existing object
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting object from its member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640915/deleting-object-from-its-member-function)

Comment: I think, that answer is not maybe complete. The answer solve digling pointer, but the question is, that returning to the member function of "dangling" object coud cause some problems in code.

Comment: *"the question is, that returning to the member function of "dangling" object coud cause some problems in code."* -- That is exactly what the other question asks ("What happens when [...] returns to the item member function?") and the answers address ("The behaviour is well defined (or not undefined).")